# I failed in IONOS deploy several times

Tags: github, github-actions, ionos

I build several websites using react and have deployed them automatically to IONOS using Github workflow so far.
But since a few days ago, I haven't been able to deploy them because of this error;

```
Trigger creation of temporary user
Failed to create temporary user
```

[image: Error Image]

I am not sure why this happens and very thankful if anybody could help me with the solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't happen. It's our fault. I'm working for IONOS and I'm directly involved in Deploy Now.

So far we use a temporary FTP user for the deployment. Currently we're working on an extended worklflow. Besides we will replace the FTP user and switch to SSH. This will hopefully end such hiccups.

As workaround you can manually re-trigger your GitHub Action.

Sorry for the inconvenience.